# Assigning values to new columns in dataframe getting error "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

**Hi**,

Basically what i am trying to do is, run a fuzzy match based on city and statecode and assign returned values to set of new columns in a dataframe. Below i have commented my tries. Couple of attempts i get a warning and for another one i get error and a warning.

I know this is just a warning. But i want to know how to resolve it.

```
def fuzzymatch_get_ratio(row):
    city, state_code = row[['City', 'State Code']]
    print('City = ', city, 'State code = ',state_code)
    cities = df_uszips[df_uszips.state_id==state_code]['city'].str.lower().unique()    
    print(process.extractOne(city, cities, scorer=fuzz.ratio))
    return process.extractOne(city, cities, scorer=fuzz.ratio)


# Warn
#test['new_city_name'], test['score'] = zip(*test.loc[:, ['City', 'State Code']].apply(fuzzymatch_get_ratio, axis=1))
#test.loc[:, 'new_city_name'], test.loc[:, 'score'] = zip(*test.loc[:, ['City', 'State Code']].apply(fuzzymatch_get_ratio, axis=1))

# Warn & object of type 'zip' has no len()
#test[['new_city_name', 'score']] = zip(*test.apply(fuzzymatch_get_ratio, axis=1))
```

Warning message is

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:10: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  # Remove the CWD from sys.path while we load stuff.
```

**Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return `pd.Series` from function, create new `DataFrame` and join to original:

```
def fuzzymatch_get_ratio(row):
        city, state_code = row['City'], row['State Code']
        print('City = ', city, 'State code = ',state_code)
        cities = df_uszips.loc[df_uszips.state_id==state_code, 'city'].str.lower().unique()    
        print(process.extractOne(city, cities, scorer=fuzz.ratio))
        return pd.Series(process.extractOne(city, cities, scorer=fuzz.ratio))

test1 = test.apply(fuzzymatch_get_ratio, axis=1)
test1.columns = ['new_city_name','score']
test = test.join(test1)
```

Another solution should be:

```
test[['new_city_name', 'score']] = test.apply(fuzzymatch_get_ratio, axis=1)
```

Comment: Still getting the same warning

Comment: When adding "test[['new_city_name', 'score']] = test.apply(fuzzymatch_get_ratio, axis=1)" received same warning with error message "ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable"

Comment: @bobby.dreamer - D you add `return pd.Series(process.extractOne(city, cities, scorer=fuzz.ratio))
` ?

Comment: Sorry, Now added and tested. Received same warning with new message " self[k1] = value[k2]"

Comment: @bobby.dreamer - if changed `test1 = test.apply(fuzzymatch_get_ratio, axis=1)` what is `print (test1.head())` ?

Comment: When assigned to new dataframe test1, there is no warning. But the result dataframe has only two columns(0,1) with values from fuzzymatch function. Below is the output
`               0   1`
`2        shorter  62`
`9    casa grande  70`
`35  garden grove  67`
`40         baker  57`
`59   los angeles  81`

Comment: Thank you, above multi-step solution(joining test1 with test) resolved the warning.